# Why I cannot call a std::shared_ptr wrapped std::function with get() method?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I define a `std::shared_ptr` object pointing to a `std::function`. Here is my code:

```
auto pointer = std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>([]{ std::cout << "hello\n"; });
```

When I want to call this function, this code can run successfully:

```cpp
(*pointer)();
```

But this code cannot compile:

```cpp
pointer.get()();
```

g++ said:

> expression cannot be used as a function

I am a bit confused about the difference of these two ways of calling the function.

Comment: What type do you think is returned by `pointer.get()`?

Comment: `(*pointer.get())();` will also work.  Dereferencing the pointer will work.

Comment: I got you guys. I know it!

Comment: You seem to think the shared pointer refers to a function. It doesn't; it refers to a `std::function` *object*, initialized from a lambda. Removing the shared pointer, create a function object via lambda, acquire its address, and attempt the same syntax, and the same problem will erupt. shared pointer has near-nothing to do with this. It just happened to be the vehicle of delivery for your misunderstanding of what a function vs. `std::function` is. The latter overloads the call operator `operator()`, but to get there, you need the object first; thereto the need for the dereference.

Comment: And fwiw, `pointer.get()->operator()()` would also work (and have your coworkers question your sanity as a bonus).